# How to get arabic number of total pages with \pagenumbering{Roman}

Tags: page-numbering

In the following code, I store the number of total pages in a macro named `\totalpages` by means of `\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}`(from packages of `lastpage` and `refcount`).

Then I compare the number by `\ifnum`, but fail for the reason of `\pagenumbering{Roman}` which make page number in non-arabic format.

I wonder if there is a way to get an arabic number of total pages even if the format of the page number is non-arabic, i.e. `\pagenumbering{Roman}` alph, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}
\def\totalpages{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
\ifnum\totalpages=3 ok \else not ok \fi\\
first page
\clearpage
second page
\clearpage
third page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your document only ever have Roman page numbers, or could there be other page numbering forms in the document?

Comment: @Mico Roman Alph and arabic

Comment: what exactly should \totalpages count? The absolute number of pages or the page number of the last page?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer  the absolute number of pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A current LaTeX writes the absolute page number into the aux-file. So no package is needed to retrieve it. In the first compilation the value is `1073741823`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
absolute page number: \@abspage@last\\
\ifnum\@abspage@last=3 ok \else not ok \fi\\
\makeatother
first page
\clearpage
second page
\clearpage
third page
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but failed to compile. `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
--- TeX said ---
l.6 absolute page number: \@abspage@last` Why?

Comment: My answer starts with "A current LaTeX". If you get an error you probably don't have a current latex.

Comment: Where to find out the current LaTex?

Comment: check your log file, it should start with something like `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4`

Comment: I updated the package `ltxbase` to the newest version(2021/1/12), but still failed to compile. How to update to the latest version of Latex?

Comment: Which TeX system do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124985/discussion-between-lyl-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer `\@abspage@last` gives the absolute number of the last page. As `\pagenumbering` reset the counter `page`, `\value{page}` or `\thepage` will give a reletive page number. So, is there a macro such like `abspage@last` to get the absolute number(count from the first page) of a middle page in an article especially when there are two or more page number styles in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pageslts` package instead of `lastpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pageslts,refcount}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\totalpages{\getpagerefnumber{LastPages}}
\ifnum\totalpages=3 ok \else not ok \fi\\
first page
\clearpage
second page
\clearpage
third page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! And is there a way to get the number of total pages in preamble?

Comment: The information comes from the `.aux` file, and this is read at `\begin{document}`. So it is not available in the preamble.